# How to close Pdf files from C#

Tags: c#, pdf, process, kill

I try to open 2 pdf files in Adobe Reader from my C# code. Lets call them A and B and A is opened before B.

Now when I try to kill the process associated with file A file B also closes down because they are linked to same process. Is there a way to close File A without closing file B.

Also when I first try to kill the process associated with File B , nothing happens and File B still remains open.

How should I go about in solving the above two scenarios.

I have handle of both the files. Is there a way I can close the handle

Comment: post the code that launches the pdf, and kills it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds to me like you should be using the Interapplication Communication API for Acrobat, which has the facility to open and close documents.  What you're doing is fairly inelegant compared with what you can get with IAC ([pdf documentation here](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/iac_api_reference.pdf)).

Answer (score 2):

you can find the process of PDF viewer of A by following code.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

public bool FindAndKillProcess(string name)
{
    //here we're going to get a list of all running processes on
    //the computer
    foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses()) {
        //now we're going to see if any of the running processes
        //match the currently running processes by using the StartsWith Method,
        //this prevents us from incluing the .EXE for the process we're looking for.
        //. Be sure to not
        //add the .exe to the name you provide, i.e: NOTEPAD,
        //not NOTEPAD.EXE or false is always returned even if
        //notepad is running
        if (clsProcess.ProcessName.StartsWith(name))
        {
            //since we found the proccess we now need to use the
            //Kill Method to kill the process. Remember, if you have
            //the process running more than once, say IE open 4
            //times the loop thr way it is now will close all 4,
            //if you want it to just close the first one it finds
            //then add a return; after the Kill
            clsProcess.Kill();
            //process killed, return true
            return true;
        }
    }
    //process not found, return false
    return false;
}
```

then call above method.

```
FindAndKillProcess("AcroRd32.exe");
```

so you can kill the process of PDF viewer.

Comment: That will kill the first Acrobat Reader it finds, which will close file A, file B, or both - who knows? Also, more to the OP than to you Brijesh, how would you know the end user is using Adobe and not some other PDF viewer? We really need to know how the PDF is launched to know how to kill it.

Comment: @brijesh but this wil also close file b because the same process is associated with file B . I dont want the file b to close .

Comment: Ok i got it. there is solution for that you need to close A first and then only open B. means at a time only one PDF will open. so no issue in that.

Comment: When you create your files in your application, you should hold onto
the filenames that were used, like, in a string array or something:

' untested air code

Private _tmpFileList As New ArrayList()

Private Function createTempFile() As String

Dim filename As String = _
System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName()

_tmpFileList.Add(filename)

End Function

Private Sub cleanupTempFiles()

For Each filename As String In _tmpFileLilst
Try
File.Delete filename
' Catch -- do something here for FileNotFound or File is open
Finally
System.IO.Path.Delete(filename)
End Try
Next

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

TRY:
if (clsProcess.ProcessName.**Contains**(name))

INSTEAD:
if (clsProcess.ProcessName.**StartsWith**(name))

```
using System.Diagnostics;

  public bool FindAndKillProcess(string name)
        {
            foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Contains(name))
                {
                    //To know if it works
                    //MessageBox.Show(clsProcess);
                    clsProcess.Kill();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            //process not found, return false
            return false;
        }

////// call the function:

            FindAndKillProcess("AcroRd32");

////// if you have been saved all the variables also you can close you main form

            FindAndKillProcess("Form_Name");
```

Answer (score -1):

I think one way to do this would be to find that instance of the program and close it from your application.  Here is an example of how to find the window and close it: http://www.mycsharpcorner.com/Post.aspx?postID=32

Since you have 2 instances of Adobe reader open you will want to determine which is which.  You can search by the text in the frame.  If you have a copy of spy++ (or a similar alternative) it makes working with outside GUI components much easier because, you can find out so much about that window, including the name, the window handle and more.